# apache2 change port from 443 to 7443

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, port

I'm using the default apache ssl conf file "default-ssl.conf"

If i leave it alone using my self signed cert i can get to the page using 443:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin my.email@gmail.com
    ServerName myhost:443
```

but once i change it to port 7443 and restart I cant get to the page.  I call the page as follows:

```
https://myip:7443/site and nothing happens but
https://myip/site works fine.
```

Each time I change it I call the apache2 restart.  Im running latest Debian in a vm.  I dont think running in a vm is the issue since port 443 works fine.  I've looked and dont really see any solution on google that helped me.  I though changing the port to 7443 would be the only thing that I would require.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must change the port in two places :

In the VirtualHost :

```
<VirtualHost _default_:7443>
```

And in the Listen directive :

```
Listen 80
Listen 7443
```

To just see what Apache understand on your ports and VirtualHosts binding, just run :

```
httpd -S
```

Comment: For debian & ubuntu, use apachectl -S as a replacement for httpd -S

Answer (score 3):

don't forget to enable SSL!

```
a2enmod ssl
```

in /etc/apache2/ports.conf , do NOT add Listen 9443 outside ssl_module!

```
Listen 9980
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 9443
</IfModule>
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:9443>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have a Listen line somewhere in your config so make sure that is set to 7443 too.

See here for more information: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Answer (score 1):

You also have to change the listening port under /etc/apache2/ports.conf (Assuming your tags are correct)

Use this command to show you all ports listening for all applications in both tcp & udp.  Apache will only be on TCP, but it's a good command to know anyway.

```
netstat -tulpn
```

Comment: Good catch haha.  Fixed.